# Visualizing HOG features MATLAB

Tags: matlab, compilation, osx-mavericks

I was trying to use the iHOG found in this link : http://web.mit.edu/vondrick/ihog/#code to visualize my HOG features. However, I had a compilation problem when following the steps. I am using MAC Mavericks MATLAB 2014a, does anyone ever met a compilation problem when using same system or maybe knows why?  This is a screenshot of the error given by MATLAB after running 'compile' as indicated by this link https://github.com/CSAILVision/ihog/blob/master/README.md#ihog-inverting-histograms-of-oriented-gradients

[image]

I tried changing the -o to -output as told bye @rayryeng.  However still I have the following error occuring:

[image]

Comment: You need to provide us with enough details about the error you are dealing with and the specification of your program. Share some code/commands you are using for this purpose.

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited it with a screenshot of the error. Hope its more clear.

Comment: Not sure.... Maybe you should ask the author on the github page and raise an issue? I'm surprised you haven't done that yet. That's the first thing I would have done.

Comment: Have already sent an email directly to the author, however he did not respond yet.  However I should ask on the github page. Thanks for your advice ;) @rayryeng

Answer (score 0):

Though this is not related to HOG, take a look at this Github page regarding `mexopencv` by Kota Yamaguchi: https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv/issues/117.  The error that you are encountering was experienced in compiling his MEX OpenCV wrappers.

Essentially, the `mex -o` option is for MATLAB versions from R2013b and below.  As of R2014a, you need to use the `-output` flag when using `mex`.  You are probably using a MATLAB version that is R2014a or later.  Therefore, go into the `compile.m` file, and change all instances of the `-o` flag to `-output`.